# Formats supported by DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We have a few queries on formats supported by DocuSign REST API

1) All the  DocuSign REST API's support XML and JSON format. is this understanding correct? Will it be supported in future as well?

2) We are integrating DocuSign API in our application, which format should be preferred - XML or JSON?

3) There are few differences between XML and JSON  request format  for each API. This results in two different XSD file for each API. Is there any way to have single XSD file to support both format?

Comment: Hi Sonia did my post answer your questions?  If so can you accept as the answer?  Thx

Comment: Yes.. Thanks a lot for quick reply

Answer (score 2):

`1)`  Yes DocuSign's REST API supports XML and JSON formatted requests, both will be supported as long as there is a REST API.

`2)` JSON is preferred since JSON payloads are much smaller than their XML equivalents (especially when the requests are bigger and more complicated)

`3)` Just use JSON and there's no need to support an XSD file.